# Return both array or nested array from API function

Tags: php, arrays, json, function, api

I am pulling an API into a WordPress site. I spoke with the company that we are pulling it from and they mentioned that for a single result it sends an array but more than one result is sent as a nested array. It wasn't this way before so this is the code that I was previously using. Is it possible to return a result for both types? I apologize in advance, my knowledge of API development is limited.

```
function get_jazzhr_jobs()
{
    $options = wp_load_alloptions();

    if (isset($options['jazz_hr_api'])) {
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.resumatorapi.com/v1/jobs/status/open?apikey={$options['jazz_hr_api']}");
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
            'Content-Type: application/json',
        ]);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $result = curl_exec($curl);
        $jobs   = json_decode($result);

        return $jobs;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

EDIT

If there is only one posting in JazzHR there will be no result shown but if there are 2 postings then both will be returned and show in the system. The $jobs is then used in the WordPress template to display the information that is received from the API. The main issue is when there is only 1 posting the array is built, but the $jobs are not populated as it has been explained to me that this snippet is working to only populate a nested array.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your precise problem. What is happening instead of what you are expecting?

Comment: By using `json_decode` without the second parameter, I believe you'll be getting an object back from this, not an array. Knowing more about how the resulting data is formatted and used would be very helpful towards solving this problem.

Comment: Hi, this question would be easily answered if you gave examples of both types of response